# Python planetary simulation, not working?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, physics

I am trying to create a program in python that calculates forces between bodies (i.e earth, moon and a hypothetical moon) and make them move according to the changes in velocity and forces. I want the values and measurements to be realistic and thus I have created a scaling factor that converts real-life distance, moon's distance to earth, in meters to pixels. I use this to convert meters to pixels or vice versa. Now the problem is that I cannot even get the moon to orbit the earth and I cannot see any faults in the calculation for the velocities and positions. Simply I have no idea why it's not working. This is my code so far:

```
from math import sin,cos,sqrt,atan2,pi
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Planet:
    dt = 1/100
    G = 6.67428e-11 #G constant
    scale = 1/(1409466.667) #1 m = 1/1409466.667 pixels
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,radius=0,color=(0,0,0),mass=0,vx=0,vy=0):
        self.x = x #x-coordinate pygame-window
        self.y = y #y-coordinate pygame-window
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.mass = mass
        self.vx = vx #velocity in the x axis
        self.vy = vy #velocity in the y axis
        
    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
    
    def orbit(self,trace):
        pygame.draw.rect(trace, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 2, 2))
        
    def update_vel(self,Fnx,Fny):
        ax = Fnx/self.mass #Calculates acceleration in x- and y-axis for body 1.
        ay = Fny/self.mass
        self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)*Planet.scale)
        self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)*Planet.scale)
        self.update_pos()
     
    def update_pos(self):
        self.x += ((self.vx * Planet.dt)) #changes position considering each body's velocity.
        self.y -= ((self.vy * Planet.dt))
        
    def move(self,body):
        dx = (self.x - body.x) #Calculates difference in x- and y-axis between the bodies
        dy = (self.y - body.y)
        r = (sqrt((dy**2)+(dx**2))) #Calculates the distance between the bodies
        angle = atan2(dy, dx) #Calculates the angle between the bodies with atan2!
        if r < self.radius: #Checks if the distance between the bodies is less than the radius of the bodies. Uses then Gauss gravitational law to calculate force.
            F = 4/3 * pi * r
            Fx = cos(angle) * F
            Fy = sin(angle) * F
        else:  
            F = (Planet.G*self.mass*body.mass)/((r/Planet.scale)**2) #Newtons gravitational formula.
            Fx = cos(angle) * F
            Fy = sin(angle) * F
        return Fx,Fy

def motion():
    for i in range(0,len(bodies)):
        Fnx = 0 #net force
        Fny = 0
        for j in range(0,len(bodies)):
            if bodies[i] != bodies[j]:
                Fnx += (bodies[i].move(bodies[j]))[0] #bodies[j] net x-force on bodies[i]
                Fny += (bodies[i].move(bodies[j]))[1] #bodies[j] net y-force on bodies[i]
            elif bodies[i] == bodies[j]:
                continue
        bodies[i].update_vel(Fnx,Fny)
        bodies[i].draw(screen)
        bodies[i].orbit(trace)
        Fnx,Fny=0,0 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900,650]) #width - height
trace = pygame.Surface((900, 650))
pygame.display.set_caption("Moon simulation")
FPS = 60 #how quickly/frames per second our game should update

earth = Planet(450,325,30,(0,0,255),5.97219*10**(24)) #450= xpos,325=ypos,30=radius
luna = Planet(450,(575/11),10,(128,128,128),7.349*10**(22),1023)
moon = Planet() #the second moon
bodies = [earth,luna]

running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running: #if user clicks close window
    clock.tick(FPS)    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.Surface.blit(screen, trace, (0, 0))
    motion()

    pygame.display.flip() #update? 

pygame.quit()
```

By changing these methods:

```
def update_vel(self,Fnx,Fny):
    ax = Fnx/self.mass #Calculates acceleration in x- and y-axis for body 1.
    ay = Fny/self.mass
    self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
    self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
    self.update_pos()
 
def update_pos(self):
    self.x += ((self.vx * Planet.dt)) #changes position considering each body's velocity.
    self.y += ((self.vy * Planet.dt))
```

I get the moon to orbit around earth however earth starts moving to the left while going up and down in a parabola shaped way (think of the trajectory of a ball bouncing only that the curves are the same height and width).

I tried changing the time *dt* and using the scaling factor in different places in my code but it did not work. By dividing the velocity with the scaling factor in update_vel I could get a non-linear path. However it is incorrect as the units of pixels and meters get mixed and the path I get is not circular at all. Thankful for any help!

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean? What and how did it not work? What happened as opposed to your expectations?

Comment: @Friedrich The moon is supposed and expected to orbit around earth, however it does not. Instead it sets off in a straight line to the right which does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your fix I am relatively certain, that your code behaves perfectly correct. The problem is that when observing this phenomenon, the earth would at all times have a slight momentum as it has been influenced in the past. The fix is giving the earth a correct starting momentum.

Change the initialization of the earth to the following:

```py
earth = Planet(450,325,30,(0,0,255),5.97219*10**(24), -24.947719394204714/2)
```

24.94... is the earths speed of the moon induced orbit. By giving the earth momentum away from the moon, it stays in place when the moons gravity starts affecting it.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works like it is supposed to now!! One question though, isn't it wrong to divide the velocity by the scaling factor instead of multiplying it since pixels and meters units get mixed together?

Comment: No worries! If my that answered your question feel free to officially accept it.

Comment: I just divided the velocity by 2 to provide the needed starting velocity. You can change that however you want. Just wanted you to quickly show the problem and one solution.

Comment: I'm thinking of the  self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
    self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale) isn't it wrong for me to do that? Shouldn't I mutliply the scaling factor instead?

Comment: Programmatically that is no concern. You just give `vx` a starting value, that is changed every time `self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale) self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)` is executed.

Comment: Is it physically correct? I would like for it to be realistic and that's why I am unsure.

Comment: Honestly this is probably the wrong forum to ask. It seems to be simulating realistically, but I can not verify that it is accurate.

Comment: Hi again! One thought, how do I calculate the starting velocity when having three bodies? It works great for the moon and earth but not when I add another body to the system. I thought of using the formula F = p/t where p is momentum and t = 0.01 to get the velocity out of the momentum but it does not work.